# Replace ":" by "_" in XML Tagnames

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml, rdf

The XML I'm using can you find here:
http://www.politie.nl/rss/ab/gemeenten/zuid-holland/rotterdam.xml.

The problem is that there are a lot of tags with a `:`. We want to replace the `:` with `_`.
Tags like `rdf:about`, `dc:date`, `rdf:resources`, should become `rdf_about`, `dc_date`, and `rdf_resources`.

We are using PHP and simplexml.

Comment: This seems like a rather unusual thing to do, and it is not in line with the way that XML QNames are used.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish in doing this?

Comment: Indeed, if you want the XML to be read by programs that understand the content (i.e. you want the feed to still be an RSS-feed that can be parsed by RSS-readers), you shouldn't touch the colons. Otherwise, you could treat the file as plain text and use a text editor such as *sed* to replace the characters.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that if you are working with this XML as XML, then you really should not try to do this.  An [XML QName](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QName) is a URI that is constructed by concatenating the namespace associated with the prefix (the part before `:`) and the local name (the part after `:`).  This means that when you see XML like:

```xml
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
     xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"
     version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <dc:date>2013-06-07T13:02:42Z</dc:date>
    <dc:language>nl</dc:language>
```

You have an element named `rss` containing an element named `channel` containing elements named `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/date` and `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/language`.  You really don't want to go any modify that, because those URIs provide the meaning of those elements.  Since the `:` is not actually a part of the resulting URI that names the element, it does not make sense to talk about replacing `:` in the name of the element, since it was never there in the first place.

If you really want to discard all that semantic information, you can, of course, use an XML processing library to read the XML that you have, and to write new XML that replaces all `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/language` with a `dc_language` element, but it is hard to see the utility in that.